# What does `pbrun -u [username] dap' do?

Tags: command-line, server, permissions

What does `pbrun -u [username] dap` do? I tried to search for the `dap` option, but not sure exactly what this `dap` stand for and its functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pbrun` is used to request that an application or command be run in a controlled account.

```
-u
    username sets the requesting user to be username.
```

In your case, the command `dap` is started for the user `[username]`, it's not an option for `pbrun`.

Sorry @Rinzwind, OP asked:

> Dap is a statistics and graphics program, that performs data management, analysis, and graphical visualization tasks which are commonly required in statistical consulting practice. Dap was written to be a free replacement for SAS, but users are assumed to have a basic familiarity with the C programming language in order to permit greater flexibility. Unlike R it has been designed to be used on large data sets.

<sub>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAP_(software))</sub>

You can download the application [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/dap/). There are also deb files.

```
cd
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/dap/dap_3.10-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i dap_3.10-1_amd64.deb
```

The command in your question would display:

```
% pbrun -u guest dap

Dap, Copyright (C) 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Dap comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY;
for details see the GNU Public License.
This is free software, and you are welcome to
redistribute it under certain conditions; see
the GNU Public License for details.

dap: no files to process
```

Answer (score 2):

`dap` there is the command being run through PowerBroker. Full usage:

```
pbrun [-v][-n][-p][-d option] [-h hostname] [-u username] command [args ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

`dap` is not an option for `pbrun`. `dap` is the command that is to run under `username` through `pbrun`.

> [Dap](http://www.gnu.org/software/dap/) is a small statistics and graphics package based on C. Version 3.0 and later of Dap can read SBS programs (based on the utterly famous, industry standard statistics system with similar initials - you know the one I mean)! The user wishing to perform basic statistical analyses is now freed from learning and using C syntax for straightforward tasks, while retaining access to the C-style graphics and statistics features provided by the original implementation. Dap provides core methods of data management, analysis, and graphics that are commonly used in statistical consulting practice (univariate statistics, correlations and regression, ANOVA, categorical data analysis, logistic regression, and nonparametric analyses).

Comment: What would the difference be if I just executed `pbrun -u [username]` instead of `pbrun -u [username]`?

Comment: I tried both ways, the first case returns a `Usage` list, while the latter command prompts for a password. Still slightly confused.

Comment: The [username] you need to change to your or an username ;)